# Lxle or/and lubuntu boot error

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu

[Booting lubuntu live usb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoFST.jpg)

Hello,

I have a specific peoblem with installing lubuntu/lxle on an old laptop, Lenovo 3000 N200.

It does not boot into grub but rather shows the graphic installation menue

Wether I choose installation or just running from live usb, loading is very slow and at the end I get errors shown in picture. I have been trying to google it but it seems quite complex to me, so I was hoping if anyone could advise or direct me what are those errors about.

[Screen errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoFST.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by "lxle lubuntu" and then lubuntu/lxle ?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: DK Bose I've tried both: lubuntu and lxle and I get the same error messages. Those are versions 18.04